# Laravel: Scripts inside of sections aren't recognizing CDN dependencies

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to run a script inside of a section with laravel which uses momnetjs.

```
<script>
        var updateClock = function() {

            var now = new Date();
            var m = new moment();

            var time = m.format('h:mm a');

            $('#clock').html(time);

            this.document.getElementById('clock').innerText(time);

            var delay = 1000 - (now % 1000);
            setTimeout(updateClock, delay);
        };
        updateClock()
    </script>
```

It is is a file which extends `main` which has this `<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>` in the body. I can't see why this wouldn't be working. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: what error you see ?

Comment: @Rodrane moment is not defined and it did the same thing with JQuery saying that $ was not defined when I tested that.

Comment: Are you loading Moment etc. *before* this <script> tag, in a synchronous manner?

Comment: which means you are not calling javascript library. are they included on the view ? if they are in layout do you extend layout view ?

Answer (score 0):

Changed the order of the imports so that the dependencies are loaded before the script. Thanks @ceejayoz and @Rodrane